# How to disable display completely in 17.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.10

I am working on a solution based on a Z series Bay Trail CPU equipped box-pc and a displaylink touch monitor. I could not manage to make Ubuntu 16.04 not freezing even with `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` workaround. Thus I tried 17.10 from pendrive, which was not freezing at all. Now I am trying to move my solution to this platform.

The goal is to use only the displaylink monitor, as there will be no VGA monitor when deployed. On 16.04 disabling the other monitor from settings was sufficient as long as I had not reconnected it.

In 17.10 on the other hand the VGA display is reenabled after reboot even if nothing is connected. Even worse, it is made primary and the touch interface is messed up.

Question: how can I forcefully disable the onboard display adapter from X on 17.10?

[Update]
I noticed that at the moment I start settings (gnome control center) widget, it is automatically restoring the desired settings.

Thank you.